# how to print the conda/anaconda version in python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I was wondering if there is a way to print the conda/anaconda version in my python code?

e.g. I mean the same way that we do for numpy like `print(numpy.__version__)`

Please not that I dont mean to do it in the terminal (like `conda --version`), but I want to do it in python code

Comment: Can you not run conda --version *within* python, e.g. `subprocess.check_output(["conda", "--version"])`

Comment: oops, that actually works. if you provide it as an answer please I can accept it.